# Is an integral fusion category pseudo-unitary over a finite field?

Tags: ct.category-theory, finite-fields, fusion-categories, unitary-fusion-category

Here are two propositions in the book [Tensor Categories](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3242743):

> Proposition 9.5.1. A pseudo-unitary fusion category admits a unique
>   spherical structure.
>
> Proposition 9.6.5. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a weakly integral fusion
>   category defined over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is
>   pseudo-unitary.

**Question**: Is Proposition 9.6.5. true for an integral fusion category defined over a finite field?

The notion of pseudo-unitary (i.e. categorical dimension equals Frobenius-Perron dimension) is defined (in the book) for a fusion category over $\mathbb{C}$, but this notion should exist without problem over a finite field in the integral case.

The combination with Proposition 9.5.1. leads to:

**Weaker question**: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an integral fusion category defined over a finite field. Is $\mathcal{C}$ spherical?